# How do I record sound intensity in decibel in an Android application using a microphone?

Tags: java, android

I need to measure ambient noise on my android application. Let's say I allow the microphone to be turned on briefly, say 30 seconds. I would like to have a decibel value in return that is representative of the sound intensity.

I do not want to record any sound. I want to simply calculate the intensity of the noise captured through the microphone for 30 seconds and turn the microphone off.

P.S. I am newbie and clueless. I'd need step by step sample code.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/jeff2900/Sound-Meter) is an open source project doing exactly what you want